# Peewee Foreignkeyfield doesn't accept appropriate foreign key field

Tags: python, database, orm, flask, peewee

I'm using the Python Peewee ORM in my flask app as a database. I've got a user defined and a ticket as follows:

```
class Ticket(db.Model):
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    event_id = CharField()
    owner = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='owned_tickets')
```

I then try to save a ticket as follows:

```
ticket = Ticket()
ticket.event_id=request.form['eventId']
ticket.owner=g.user
ticket.save()
```

but I get a `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'` with a (huge) stacktrace which I pasted below. The weird thing is that I defined the field to be of type `ForeignKeyField(User)`, but it appears to ask for a string/number.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 758, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kramer65/dev/repos/tc/app/views/webviews.py", line 120, in myTickets
    ticket.save()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 3511, in save
    pk_from_cursor = self.insert(**field_dict).execute()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 2565, in execute
    return self.database.last_insert_id(self._execute(), self.model_class)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 2126, in _execute
    sql, params = self.sql()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 2556, in sql
    return self.compiler().generate_insert(self)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1530, in generate_insert
    return self.build_query(clauses, alias_map)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1359, in build_query
    return self.parse_node(Clause(*clauses), alias_map)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1320, in parse_node
    sql, params, unknown = self._parse(node, alias_map, conv)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1295, in _parse
    sql, params = self._parse_map[node_type](node, alias_map, conv)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1248, in _parse_clause
    node.nodes, alias_map, conv, node.glue)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1337, in parse_node_list
    node_sql, node_params = self.parse_node(node, alias_map, conv)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1320, in parse_node
    sql, params, unknown = self._parse(node, alias_map, conv)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1295, in _parse
    sql, params = self._parse_map[node_type](node, alias_map, conv)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1248, in _parse_clause
    node.nodes, alias_map, conv, node.glue)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1337, in parse_node_list
    node_sql, node_params = self.parse_node(node, alias_map, conv)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1320, in parse_node
    sql, params, unknown = self._parse(node, alias_map, conv)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1295, in _parse
    sql, params = self._parse_map[node_type](node, alias_map, conv)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1248, in _parse_clause
    node.nodes, alias_map, conv, node.glue)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1337, in parse_node_list
    node_sql, node_params = self.parse_node(node, alias_map, conv)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1320, in parse_node
    sql, params, unknown = self._parse(node, alias_map, conv)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1295, in _parse
    sql, params = self._parse_map[node_type](node, alias_map, conv)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1236, in _parse_param
    params = [node.conv(node.value)]
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 1052, in db_value
    return self.to_field.db_value(value)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/peewee.py", line 674, in db_value
    return value if value is None else self.coerce(value)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 390, in <lambda>
    __int__ = lambda x: int(x._get_current_object())
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'
```

[EDIT]
Okay, the error seems to be located somewhere else than in the code I posted so far. I tried adding a Ticket from the python interactive interpreter, which works perfectly well. When I `print type(g.user)` I get the type `<class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy'>`. This is pretty weird, because I am able to simply print out the correct `g.user.username` and `g.user.password`. The `User` class looks as follows:

```
class User(relDb.Model, BaseUser):
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
```

I set the `g.user` object as follows:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user
```

Does anybody have any other idea of why `g.user` gives a `werkzeug.local.LocalProxy` instead of a User class? All tips are welcome!

Comment: What is the the code of your user class as well as user db primary key?

Comment: Have you tried `to_field` parameter and pointing it to the correct user class' primary key field?

Comment: Ditto on sharing your `User` model.

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi - Turns out `g.user` is of type `werkzeug.local.LocalProxy` instead of type `User` (see my edit to the question). Any idea why that is?

Comment: @coleifer - I just made an edit to my question. It turns out the `g.user` object is of type `werkzeug.local.LocalProxy` instead of type `User`. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi - Alright, I fixed it; I now use zg.user._get_current_object()` to get the actual object to be able to store it in the DB. Thanks for your time and effort though!

Comment: Awesome work, glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some more reading I found the solution. Since `g` never returns the underlying objects, but merely acts as a proxy for passing on commands to the actual object and returning the results, I need to get the object to which `g.user` points, which is done like so:

```
ticket.owner = g.user._get_current_object()
```

Saving this in my Ticket model works like a charm.

ps. Since this works, I use it now. But if there's anything wrong with this approach, I would love to hear it.